# Sorting while using multiple tables in Search model.php in Yii2

Tags: php, sorting, yii2

i have 2 table State And Country now i am showing state list in state module and i and i am showing country also in the state list like

```
StateName    CountryName    ActionButtons
Victoria     Australia      edit | delete
NSW          Australia      edit | delete
Auckland     New Zealand    edit | delete
California   USA            edit | delete
```

i want to sort both column State and Country name but country name sorting is not working here.

as i worked on YII version 1.1.16 i made it using `CSort` but i don't know how to use it in YII2. please help me to make this work in YII2.

Comment: show your code please

Comment: hey @scaisEdge thanks for looking i found solution

Answer (score 1):

I found solution it will help to someone

i added `setSort` for dataprovider in stateSearch model

```
 $dataProvider->setSort([
            'attributes' => [
                'country_name' => [
                    'asc' => ['country_name' => SORT_ASC, 'country_name' => SORT_ASC],
                    'desc' => ['country_name' => SORT_DESC, 'country_name' => SORT_DESC],
                    'default' => SORT_ASC
                ],  
                'state_name' => [
                    'asc' => ['state_name' => SORT_ASC, 'state_name' => SORT_ASC],
                    'desc' => ['state_name' => SORT_DESC, 'state_name' => SORT_DESC],
                    'label' => 'state_name',
                    'default' => SORT_ASC
                ],                
            ]
        ]);
```

and

```
$query->andFilterWhere([
            'state_name' => $this->state_name,
            'country_name' => $this->country_name,
        ]);
```

and its working!!!

with referring below link

> http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/